# .htaccess Hide a Single GET Variable?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm looking for a simple *.htaccess rewrite rule* that will mask the first `GET` variable:

```
examplesite.com/?p=test -> examplesite.com/test
```

And if parameters need to be passed to the site:

```
examplesite.com/?p=test&param=1234 -> examplesite.com/test?param=1234
```

Feels like it should be simple but I'm struggling.

---- Update: ----

Forgot to mention, I'd like the parameter to be accepted as a-z 0-9 with underscores and dashes, any case. (I'm bad with Regular Expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Code to your .htaccess file. Not tested but sure it will work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ examplesite.com/?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```